# Accessing list of Instances returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, jboss7.x, cdi

I tried to replace our Factory class that returns classes by string name using reflection with a CDI-based method.

So I put an `@Inject @Any Instance<IData> possibleCandidates` as a class variable. Then in the `getIDataInstanceByClassname(String className)` I'm creating an instance via `Class.forName` and compare it to every instance in the `possibleCandidates` list to then return a matching "injectable" instance.

However accessing `possibleCandidates` ends up in a `NullPointerException`. Whether I start a `for` loop or use `possibleCandidates.iterator()`. However, inspecting the variable does not return null but `InstanceImpl<T>` filled with various values.

How come accessing it produces a NPE?

Some code:

```
@Instance
@Any
private Instance<IData> possibleCandidates;

public IData getClassByClassname( String className ) {

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName( className );
        Iterator<IData> it = possibleCandidates.iterator(); // NPE gets thrown here
        while ( it.hasNext() ) {
            IData dataInstance = it.next();
            if ( dataInstance.getClass().equals( clazz ) ) {
                return dataInstance;
            }
        }
    }
    catch( Exception e ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code, and the complete stack trace, would help you (and us) find where the problem is.

Comment: Couldn't get the stack trace in Debug mode, so I added another `log.error(e.getMessage(), e)` which finally prints the stack trace. Seems like there is a problem in one of the injected classes which causes this "hidden" NullPointerException.

Comment: Odd. More info via a stack trace or other code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was one class in that list, that produced a NullPointerException at construction time which caused any access to the Instance list to fail. I could not see the cause of the NPE in the Debugging mode, but when I added some logging, the underlying reason was clear.

So, remember kids: Always rethrow exceptions in the catch block or dome something with it. But never throw a different exception without putting the original exception as the cause into it.